# WPF Switching Views through Command Button

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm quite new to WPF and what I'm trying to do is switch views through different command buttons.. this is my current code...

Basically I have two buttons in my MainView, SetupLan and SetupSerialPort.
For simplicity, I'm currently trying to make SetupSerialPort working first. But when I click the button for it, the command executes but the view doesn't change...

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainViewModel}">
        <Views:MainView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SetupLanViewModel}">
        <Views:SetupLanView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SetupSerialPortViewModel}">
        <Views:SetupSerialPortView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

**MainViewModel**

```
public DisplaySetupSerialPortCommand SetupSerialPort
{
    get; set;
}

public MainViewModel()
{
    SetupSerialPort = new DisplaySetupSerialPortCommand(this);
}
```

**MainView**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Height="50" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"Command="{Binding SetupLan}">Lan</Button>
    <Button Height="50" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding SetupSerialPort}">Serial Port</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

**DisplaySetupSerialPortCommand**

```
class DisplaySetupSerialPortCommand : ICommand
{
    private BaseViewModel _baseViewModel;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public DisplaySetupSerialPortCommand(BaseViewModel baseViewModel)
    {
        _baseViewModel = baseViewModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _baseViewModel.ViewModel = new SetupSerialPortViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to have SetupLan and SetupSrialPort be interchangeable?

Comment: @d.moncada There's a separate view for both setups. and I'm also planning to have separate commands for it. Say for serialport, when the serialport button is pressed, it will execute the serial port command and show the serial port view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

Your `command` is not doing anything at all, it's simply just creating a `ViewModel`. You need to add additional logic for this to work.

If you want to switch out the `DataTemplate` to different views, you will need to implement some type of `Trigger`.

First, update your `DataTemplates` to have an associated key.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainViewModel}" x:Key="MainView">
        <Views:MainView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SetupLanViewModel}" x:Key="Lan">
        <Views:SetupLanView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SetupSerialPortViewModel}" x:Key="SerialPort">
        <Views:SetupSerialPortView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

By adding a key, it will allow you to reference each one, where/when needed.

Next, inside your `MainWindow.xaml`, this is where the `Triggers` will occur.
Update your `ContentControl` to `Trigger` and switch it's `DataTemplate` based on some condition. In this case, the condition I created is called ViewType.

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MainView}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewType}" Value="SerialPort">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SerialPort}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewType}" Value="Lan">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Lan}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Lastly, you will need to have a `ViewType` property, and set that property based on the specific command that was executed. Add to `ViewType` property your BaseViewModel since the command has a reference to this.

```
public string ViewType
{
    get { return _viewType; }
    set
    {
        _viewType = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Now, you can change the ViewType whenever the command is clicked.

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    _baseViewModel.ViewType = "SerialPort";
    _baseViewModel.ViewModel = new SetupSerialPortViewModel();
}
```

**Note**: I used a string for a ViewType type just for demo purposes only. You would probably want to use an enumeration instead.

Comment: Where did RaisePropertyChanged() come from?

Comment: I tried your solution but commenting out RaisePropertyChanged().. though nothing happens, button still executes but the view doesn't change

Comment: It's working now :) so I needed to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to BaseViewModel and raise that PropertyChanged event when the viewType changes.

Comment: Thank you very much!.
I just want to ask if you know any resources/links that tackles WPF concepts  (for beginners)..

Comment: Yep, I assumed you had implemented INotifyPropertyChanged already in your BaseViewModel (which is what most do). Regarding resources for beginners, WPF unleashed is a pretty good book.